# How to use cron and rsync to transfer files from remote server to local path

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, rsync

I am looking for some knowledge to help me understand why my use of cron fails when using rsync to transfer files from remote server to local path.

My aim is to have a scheduled cron job run at a set time and successfully execute my transfer script

From numerous Google searches I put together the following rsync command:

```
rsync --protect-args --remove-source-files --chmod=Du=rw,Dgo=rw,Fu=rw,Fog=r -apvzrc pi@192.168.0.10:/media/pi/USBSTORAGE32/ /media/Data_1/"James' Files"/
```

I have set up the remote server so it doesn't ask for a password by using ssh-keygen rsa to generate a public key which is stored in an authorised_keys file. I log into the 'local' machine using SSH and type the command to 'pull' the files from the remote server to the local machine.

Once I'd tested the rsync command above I thought I had it nailed so popped this into a script which then added to cron via crontab. My added line looks like this

```
55 * * * * sudo /home/jlivin25/bin/myscripts/sync.sh > /var/log/james/cronsync.log 2>&1
```

And my script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rsync --protect-args --remove-source-files --chmod=Du=rw,Dgo=rw,Fu=rw,Fog=r -apvzrc pi@192.168.0.10:/media/pi/USBSTORAGE32/ /media/Data_1/"James' Files"/
```

The scheduled task fails to run as expected, cron trys to run the script but the following error message is logged in my log file:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

And its at this point that I'm stuck, because by 'googling' the above message I get lots of differing reasons that what I have done is not working. I'm not sure where to chase the error to, is the issue with my use of cron, ssh or rsync.

Any help would be appreciated.

littlejeem

Comment: Seams you have something needing your terminal. Maybe your ssh agent

Comment: Try in the /etc/cron.d or directly with the crontab -e of your root user to avoid having to sudo

Comment: Hey @quazardous, I hadn't thought of that (crontab of root) I will give it a go and report back. Thanks for rapid response.

Comment: @quazardous I moved my desired cron job to root crontab. Removed the sudo from the command. I also generated an rsa public key for root user and am testing tonight. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

So very likely `cron` is a daemon that is executed by user `cron` in your system. When the `cron` daemon decides to run a cronjob, it does so as the `cron` user. But very likely the `cron` user is not allowed to *sudo* in your system, so this accounts for the mentioned *sudo* error (as *sudo* usually asks for a password on forbidden uses, but in this case there is no terminal or password request program for `cron` user to acquire one).

A way of having this confirmed is to run something like `env | sort >/tmp/environment.log` in the start of your script and check for key variables (such as `USER` and `HOME`) after execution. You can even compare the environment with the one when your script is executed manually.

I believe an approach here is obviously to configure *sudo* to allow `cron` to run your script as the "correct" user. Another approach would be to make your script source (or replicate) some of the environment of the "correct" user, so *sudo* would not be required. I cannot tell which one is more effective to your goals.

Comment: Hello @coolparadox thanks for taking the time to write an answer. I will check and see what I get from `env | sort >/tmp/environment.log` tomorrow. I suspect that I have made several assumptions in what I've done that are preventing a successful outcome.